# How to get count of screen_view events in firebase analytics?

Tags: firebase-analytics

1. In Google analytics, it's possible to see how many unique visitors opened a page but in Firebase analytics we can only see the % total and Avg time for each screen_name. Is there a way to see the actual count instead of %age or will we need BigQuery help for this?

We are planning to use BigQuery to generate custom reports but would like to know if there is any way to generate the screen_view count reports from the firebase dashboard itself.

Comment: Im passing for this right now, how did you solve? I was able to integrate with Data Studio, but I wanted to check if the data is correct.